# Removing words from string with regex C# that are in between /

Tags: c#, regex

need to get rid of "organization" within a string with regex, the problem is organization is followed by different text for example it could be

```
Hosted/Organizationminor/
or
Hosted/Organizationmajor/
```

result for both should be

```
Hosted//
```

Comment: Can you be guaranteed there are only two `/` in the string or could you need to deal with the case when there are more?

Comment: yes there could be more

Comment: What result do you need if there are more than `/`? Can you edit your question to include more examples, as well as show us what you have attempted so far?

Comment: What would be the expected behaviour if there were more? `a/b/c/` should become `a///` and `a/b/c/d/` should become `a////` or will the `/` be matched? Or will you only ever remove text if it starts with Organization? You need to fully specify the requirements. You should also preferably show what you've tried so we know where you are stuck. eg do you know nothing about regular expressions (in which case do you definitely want to use them) or have you got a regex that matches but that won't actually remove the text or something else...

Answer (score 1):

The following will find instances of "Organization" followed by any number of non-"/" characters, provided that "Organization" is preceded by "/" and that the whole thing is followed by "/". I'm using zero-width look-behind and look-ahead assertions, so that you can drop this in as the Regex and substitute it with an empty string.

```
(?=/)Organization[^/]*(?=</)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-regex solution with LINQ.

Since the task is to remove a known string `"Organization"` followed with any chars other than `/` after a `/` you can split the string with `/` and just  rebuild the string using LINQ to only select the necessary parts:

```
string.Join("/", s.Split('/')
    .Select(m => m.StartsWith("Organization") ? "" : m) // Empty the parts starting with the known word
);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/h2qeUw)

Comment: But wouldn't the resulting string not have the `//` at the end that the OP was expecting?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw Just look at the demo at IDEONE. The empty items are not removed, `string.Join` will join them with `/`, too.

Comment: Can't hit that link here at work--blocked. But duh on me, I just looked closer and correctly understood your `Join` call.